# How to get Category URL from category entity in Shopware 6?

Tags: symfony, e-commerce, backend, shopware

I am taking some categories from the category repository and want to get their URLS to make links in the future.

```
$categoryRepository = $this->container->get('sales_channel.category.repository')->search($criteria, $event->getSalesChannelContext())->getElements();
```

Is there some getter method that can help me in achieving that result?

This is the entity:

```
Shopware\Core\Content\Category\CategoryEntity
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add the corresponding associations to the `$criteria` you're able to get the Urls by `$categoryEntity->getSeoUrls()`. That will return a `SeoUrlCollection` in which you're able to perform `getPathInfo()` and `getSeoPathInfo()`.

```php
foreach ($categoryRepository as $catEntity) {
    foreach ($catEntity->getSeoUrls()->getElements() as $seoUrlEntity) {
        $seoUrlEntity->getPathInfo();
        $seoUrlEntity->getSeoPathInfo();
    }
}
```

Comment: in criteria I am adding seourls like this, but it does not do anything. Is this the right way to do it?
$criteria->addAssociation('category.seoUrls');

Comment: The Association you need is 'seoUrls'. The needed name is always found in the EntityDefinition. In your case `\Shopware\Core\Content\Category\CategoryDefinition`.